# View panel and pager in different facets

Tags: controls, xpages, pager, xsp

If have a custom control with 2 facets. One to hold e.g. a view panel and another for holding the corresponding pager control for that view panel. The source is that:

```
<xc:ccPanel footer="true" title="View">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:div xp:key="footer">
                            <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next"
                                partialRefresh="true" id="pager1" for="viewPanel1">
                            </xp:pager>
                        </xp:div>
                        <xp:viewPanel rows="5" id="viewPanel1"
                            xp:key="body" viewStyle="width:100%">
                            <xp:this.data>
                                <xp:dominoView var="view1"
                                    viewName="all">
                                </xp:dominoView>
                            </xp:this.data>
                            <xp:viewColumn columnName="$0"
                                id="viewColumn1">
                                <xp:viewColumnHeader
                                    value="Creation date" id="viewColumnHeader1">
                                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                            </xp:viewColumn>
                        </xp:viewPanel>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                </xc:ccPanel>
```

It is odd but the panel does not control the view panel, clicking on any control link does not have any effect on the view. I couldn't figure out what I am missing here.
Maybe you can? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I found out that the view is controlled but the pager does not reflect the changes by e.g. showing the current page.

Answer (score 0):

The pager works when it is a child facet of the xp:viewPanel.  Try commenting out your xp:div and just enable the pager in the properties for the viewPanel on the Display tab ... enable pager for the header, footer or both.  Everything should then be properly tied together and your pager(s) should work with your viewPanel.

If you stick with your current design with the pager outside of the viewPanel facets then remove the partialRefresh="true" from the pager.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I experienced that is it not mandatory to place a pager in the view panel's facets (though it is created by default in that way). The problem described here is that pager and view panel reside in different facets of my custom control. I was curious if someone knows a trick or workaround to construct this.

Comment: Try removing the partialRefresh="true" on the pager.